# Translation of color/toric code to a small network of solid-state spins

Tags: architecture, experimental-realization, solid-state, error-correction

Within [Quantum Error Correction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_error_correction) and [stabilizer codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stabilizer_code), [toric codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toric_code)/*surface codes* are very tempting, mainly for their high error threshold. For more background please check up, in our Physics sister (aunt?) site: [Quantum Error Correction: Surface code vs. color code](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/169176/quantum-error-correction-surface-code-vs-color-code).

However, these codes require fairly specific measurements in specific bases, which I find hard to translate in practice, especially into my language of interest which is spin states in a solid-state few-spin collection. To see my motivation, here is a not-quite successful attept from a few years ago, using a more naïve QEC scheme: "[Quantum Error Correction with magnetic molecules](https://arxiv.org/abs/1404.6912)".

So, the problem:

- I am designing a realistic (molecular/supramolecular) network of 7 spins 1/2 (or something almost equivalent, see [Is qubit/qudit terms, where is the experimental limit between an S=3/2 and 2·S=1/2?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/1867/is-qubit-qudit-terms-where-is-the-experimental-limit-between-an-s-3-2-and-2-s-1))
- a necessary first: what are the operations/measurements that I need to be able to do? here assume I'm able to do [Pulsed electron paramagnetic resonance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulsed_electron_paramagnetic_resonance) to address every transition coherently
- and, as a consequence, what is a good coupling scheme between my spins so that the required number of physical operations is reasonable?

*Related: [How does the size of a toric code torus affect its ability to protect qubits?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/2098/how-does-the-size-of-a-toric-code-torus-affect-its-ability-to-protect-qubits)*

Comment: It seems most of the [tag:solid-state] questions you asked on this site have gone unanswered. I wonder if we can bring in more experimentalists to answer such questions.

Comment: I try to post questions that are interesting, related to my research work and at on-topic for QC. If a train full of solid-state quantum physicists (experimentalists or otherwise) arrives, their answers sure will be welcome :) In any case, I'd say this discussion belongs to the chat rather than here.

Comment: Would Ising type anyonic interaction be applicable, in which case the frustrations are local, something in adiabatic regime, could be tried then- If there are any Ising anyons that are implemented by adiabatic(or even annealing schemes).

Comment: @agaitaarino: Thanks for adding my question to it!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the translation into physics, but the circuit you want for the most basic demonstration is the following:
[image]
Here, $|+\rangle=(|0\rangle+|1\rangle)/\sqrt{2}$, and the gates are controlled-not gates and controlled-phase gates. The state $|\psi\rangle$ can be any input state initially. The first time the circuit is run prepares the $|\psi\rangle$ qubits in a 4-qubit Toric code (up to some corrections depending on what measurement results you got). Repeat the measurements again, and you get a round of error correction. In effect, what the first qubit is doing is measuring the expectation value of the observable $XXXX$ on the Toric code qubits, while the second qubit measures the $ZZZZ$ observable.

I seem to remember that Jiannis Pachos (and coauthors) explicitly described the smallest Toric code implementation possible (which I guess was this version), but I can't seem to find the paper. I had assumed that JamesWooton would have jumped in by now to tell you where that paper is. It must be commented, however, that such a small size of Toric Code is completely hopeless for error correcting properties; you cannot even correct for single-qubit errors!

Comment: Although that is not at all the final result that I aimed for, that was already helpful! And even before going into the required translation into spins, I need a few further clarifications on the circuit. By |+> you mean the linear combination of |0> and |1>, or something different? By ZZZ you actually mean ZZZZ? For some reason I wrote I needed 7 spins but it actually works with 6?

Comment: @agaitaarino Yes, exactly. I think you *can* make this 6-qubit case (where the actual code is on 4 qubits) but it's just an in-prinicple demonstration with completely hopeless error correcting properties. You need quite a few more qubits to make it worthwhile (perhaps 9? code qubits and however many you use for stabilizer measurements)